# Multiple characters with the same name in the bible

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, tanach

In the Bible most of the names are unique, especially for the main characters.

As far as I know there is only one Abraham and only one Moses etc. 
There are some names that appear more than once like [Eliab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliab), [Abiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_Old_Testament_figures,_A%E2%80%93K#Abiel), [Ahaziah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahaziah) and more...

My questions are:

1. Does anybody know if there is a list of all these names?
2. Is there any reference by Parshanim to the fact that the main characters appear once?
3. Is there a reference by Parshanim to the names that are not unique?

=== EDIT=== 
I was just showed that Saul that is quit a main character is not unique there 2 more [Sauls](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.46.10?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) in Breishit

Comment: There's also a Shmuel in Bamidbra

Comment: @DoubleAA great thanks! i found it https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.34.20?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: I had been wondering about duplicate names and wasn't sure if there were any.  When I got into my research of who was around at the start of the Exodus (and names I could use to fill in the gaps for those not given names), I discovered that duplicate names are all over the place.  While most "main characters" are not duplicated, some are.  I don't know of a list though.

Comment: There are quite a few. E.g. Lamech, Devorah, Tamar, Yehoshua, Eliphaz, Michah, Pinchas, Gad, Hoshea, Nachor, etc.